# Conteo de varias tablas atreves de variables

Tags: postgresql

Buen día, necesito una ayuda. Lo que quiero es lo siguiente es que con los nombres de tablas que me arroja el query del cursor, haga de manera individual el conteo de los registros de cada una de ellas, para eso tengo el siguiente PL pero este no reconoce la variable. Que me recomendarían?.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    reg record;
    tabla text;
    cant_reg int;
    cur_prin cursor for 
    SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema='public'
            AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
            AND table_name = 'usuarios_cartas';
BEGIN
    FOR reg IN cur_prin LOOP
        **tabla := reg.table_name;**
        RAISE NOTICE 'Variable tabla %', tabla;
        SELECT count(1) 
            INTO cant_reg
            **FROM concat('public.',reg.table_name);**
        RAISE NOTICE 'variable cant_reg %',cant_reg;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Lo que espero por ejemplo del PL que agregue como es una sola tabla arroje el valor 64 que es la cantidad de registro que posee esa tabla. Algo así:

```
    Variable tabla usuarios_cartas 
    variable cant_reg 64
```

Pero esta es devolviendo esto:

```
    Variable tabla usuarios_cartas 
    variable cant_reg 1
```